# Where do I change the default iTunes U download settings?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, itunes-u

I want to change the default settings for iTunes U in iTunes 11. I can not find anything however relating to podcasts or iTunes U in the preference window.
Now I need to change the `Episodes to keep` property for every course. I want to change it for all the courses at once. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is a little bit hidden:

- Go to iTunes U in iTunes 11
- right or <kbd>command</kbd>-click on one of your courses.
- click on settings
- a view for settings will apper - at first it will only look like you can edit the settings for the selected course
- from the dropdown menu choose iTunes U default settings and you can edit the settings for every course according to your likings.

Here is a screenshot (in german but I think you will get the idea):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into the settings dialog for one of your courses.

You will see a drop-down menu next to `"Settings for:"`

Click on that, and at the top of that menu you will see `"iTunes U Default"`

You can change settings there.